# Named Pipe C# Server + Python Client

Tags: python, c#, named-pipes

I'm trying to create a C# Named Pipe server with a Python client.  The Python client is supposed to send an instruction to the C# server, and the server return some data based on the instruction.  The C# server will run all the time waiting for instructions from Python.  Basically like web API server.  However only using named pipes and not http.

So far I was able to put the code below together by modifying some examples that I found on Stackoverflow.  However, it simply does not work.  The message from Python to C# is never received, although the connection established. I'm not even sure if a message can be sent from Python.  I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help will be appreciated.

**C# Server**

```
public class Server
    {
        private NamedPipeServerStream PipeServer { get; set; }

        public void StartServer()
        {
            NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("TestServer", PipeDirection.InOut, 10, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 1024, 1024);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
                    string instruction;

                    //Receive instruction message
                    instruction = sr.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(instruction);

                    //Do some database calls

                    //Send data back to Python client
                    sw.WriteLine("Data");
                    sw.Flush();
                    pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
                finally
                {
                    pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
                    if (pipeServer.IsConnected) { pipeServer.Disconnect(); }
                }
            } while (true);
        }
    }
```

**Python Client**

```
import time
import sys
import win32pipe, win32file, pywintypes

def PipeClient():
    print("pipe client")
    quit = False

    while not quit:
        try:
            handle = win32file.CreateFile(
                r'\\.\pipe\TestServer',
                win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                0,
                None,
                win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                None
            )
            res = win32pipe.SetNamedPipeHandleState(handle, win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, None, None)
            if res == 0:
                print(f"SetNamedPipeHandleState return code: {res}")
            while True:

                # Send instruction data to c# server
                win32file.WriteFile(handle, str.encode('Instruction 1'))

                # Receive data from Python client
                resp = win32file.ReadFile(handle, 64*1024)
                print(f"message: {resp}")
          
        
        except pywintypes.error as e:
            if e.args[0] == 2:
                print("no pipe, trying again in a sec")
                time.sleep(1)
            elif e.args[0] == 109:
                print("broken pipe, bye bye")
                quit = True


t = PipeClient()
```

Comment: You're doing a `ReadLine` in your C# code, but you never write a newline (`'\n'`) in your Python code, so it's never going to see a line.

Comment: @TimRoberts wow thanks that was indeed the problem.  Can you believe it.  I will accept this answer if you post it.  At least I have a full example here for any future person looking for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a `ReadLine` in your C# code, but you never write a newline (`'\n'`) in your Python code, so it's never going to see a complete line.